# Free, web-based finance tracking with tag/label support?

Tags: software, tracking

My current solution for tracking finances is a google docs spreadsheet, with a new sheet every month. Overall, I'm quite happy with it. I keep track of where money was spent, on what, and I try to tag everything with one or two keywords (e.g. "work lunch", "entertainment, board games").

The only thing I'd really like is to be able to actually *do* something with those tags. Ideally, I'd like to be able to see e.g. how much particular tags make up of my overall expenditures, and as an added bonus (not really important), if I could view historical spending trends on a per-tag basis that would also be nice.

Now here's the catch... I want something simple and relatively spartan. I tried mint.com for a while, and I liked it, but I came to rely on it and its integration with my bank, and when that broke I'd already gotten out of the habit of tracking things manually.

Basically, I want something where...

1. I can enter every expense manually
2. I can import existing data (willing and able to coax the data into whatever form is necessary)
3. Supports tagging/labeling, and a single transaction can support multiple tags
4. Supports multiple accounts (e.g. multiple checking and/or savings accounts, and also cash on hand)
5. Is available online, or otherwise easy for me to edit from both work and home without having to put any thought into keeping things in sync.
6. Free (ad-supported or 'freemium' is fine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[hledger](http://hledger.org) fits your criteria, have you tried it ? Here's the [web interface](http://demo.hledger.org).

Answer (score 0):

Mint.com does all of that (except for the cash at hand).

Comment: Like I said, I tried mint and it just ended up screwing me up. Maybe it would work if I didn't do the bank integration stuff, but I've already got a bad taste in my mouth for the site and it's a lot more heavy-weight than I want.